# Does reledmac not work with beamer?

Tags: beamer, reledmac

I'd like to reproduce some of my critical text from my dissertation in a presentation, but it seems that reledmac does not work with beamer. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}

\frame {
    test
}
\end{document}
```

Running through pdflatex gives an error:
`! LaTeX Error: Command \lemma already defined.`

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: So, I found the workaround for this. Declare with: `\documentclass[notheorems]{beamer}`

Comment: Yes, that is. Unfortunatly, there is a name conflict.

Comment: this seems to be useful information, and i haven't found another question on the topic.  so if you post a self-answer, it won't get lost.

Comment: As @barbarabeeton said, please post the workaround you found as an answer, and “accept” the answer. Then you'll have made the site useful to others with the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

> Converting [@Aleksandr comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412375/does-reledmac-not-work-with-beamer#comment1029507_412375) into a CW answer

The following workaround works with lualatex:

```
\documentclass[notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround for the use with lualatex:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\lemma\undefined
\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```